# Put request giving a Cast to Object ID error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For some reason I am getting the following error when attempting to update a string via a PUT request in the following schema:

```
`var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var litterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: String,
   description: String
});

   module.exports = mongoose.model("Litters", litterSchema);`
```

I'm confused because I have an identical schema and route which seems to work with no issues.  I'm wondering if I've corrupted something in one of my dependencies?  No idea where to go with this.

Here is my route:

```
router.put("/:id", middleware.adminLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // req.body.litter on next line pulls from the square brackets on edit.ejs, this way don't have to define object here.
    Litters.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.litter, function(err, updatedLitter){
        if(err){
            res.send("ERROR");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/litters/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the error that I'm getting:

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23204_goldendoodle.jpg" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23204_goldendoodle.jpg" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23204_goldendoodle.jpg',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }
```

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.litter, null, 4))`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update ObjectId value with String that is not possible and will give type cast error.

**Check your "litter" object. It have "http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/01/file_23204_goldendoodle.jpg" value at path "_id".**